# where can I find zoom activity logs?

Tags: zoom-sdk

I am a new Application packager and the requirement is as follows:
If zoom.exe is present and not used in 180 days - uninstall
If zoom.exe is present and used in 180 days - update

I am trying to see logs but the folder is empty. I found that Zoom does not store a log of the last accessed date within its files on your device. I manually enabled logs by adding "enable.memlog.file=true" but it doesn't show the previous logs.
Any help I can get to know the last accessed date of zoom?

Thanks in advance.